# Why is svg loading delayed only in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have a png, svg file that is already hidden when loaded. And I tried to operate this png and svg with JavaScript without displaying it. This worked on Firefox but not on the latest version of Chrome.

**Question**

The reason is that Chrome doesn't read the svg file until it displays (`display: block`) the `object` element. Is this a bug in Chrome? Is there a way to solve this and achieve the same behavior as Firefox?

```html
<img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" style="display: none">

<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="display:none;"></object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways to hide elements, you can set the width, height to 0, and overflow to hidden for example, or make the element fixed, and move it above the top, etc...

**Example:**

```js
function showLoaded(idx) {
  console.log('loaded ' + idx);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" style="display: none">

<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload="showLoaded(1)" style="display: none;"></object>

<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload="showLoaded(2)" style="position: fixed; top: -10000px;"></object>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
By the way, will I be unable to use the `display` property in Firefox in the future? Or will the `display` property be available in Chrome this way?

Comment: It's better to use something that will work for all browsers, then try to tailor a different one for each of them. Regarding Chrome's support - this seems like an optimisation (don't load unneeded elements), so I don't really know if it's something they are going to change.